# In pandas, what would be the idiomatic way to select multiple columns based on different patterns?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm trying to replicate some of R4DS's `dplyr` exercises using Python's `pandas`, with the `nycflights13.flights` dataset. What I want to do is select, from that dataset:

- Columns through `year` to `day` (inclusive);
- All columns that end with "delay";
- The `distance` and `air_time` columns

In the book, Hadley uses the following syntax:

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("nycflights13")

flights_sml <- select(flights,
   year:day,
   ends_with("delay"),
   distance,
   air_time
)
```

In pandas, I came up with the following "solution":

```py
import pandas as pd
from nycflights13 import flights

flights_sml = pd.concat([
    flights.loc[:, 'year':'day'],
    flights.loc[:, flights.columns.str.endswith("delay")],
    flights.distance,
    flights.air_time,
], axis=1)
```

Another possible implementation:

```py
flights_sml = flights.filter(regex='year|day|month|delay$|^distance$|^air_time$', axis=1)
```

But I'm sure this is **not** the idiomatic way to write such DF-operation. I digged around, but haven't found something that fits in this situation from `pandas` API.

Comment: fwiw, I find your first implementation fairly idiomatic as far as pandas goes.

Comment: Thanks @modesitt, but as Shaido pointed out, it creates lots of DataFrames in the process, meaning extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. This will create multiple dataframes/series and then concatenate them together, resulting in a lot of extra work. Instead, you can create a list of the columns you want to use and then simply select those.

For example (keeping the same column order):

```py
cols = ['year', 'month', 'day'] + [col for col in flights.columns if col.endswith('delay')] + ['distance', 'air_time']
flights_sml = flights[cols]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the dataset's columns info, we can utilize [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```py
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('year|month|day|delay|distance|air_time')]
```

```
   year  month  day  dep_delay  arr_delay  air_time  distance
0  2013      1    1        2.0       11.0     227.0      1400
1  2013      1    1        4.0       20.0     227.0      1416
2  2013      1    1        2.0       33.0     160.0      1089
3  2013      1    1       -1.0      -18.0     183.0      1576
4  2013      1    1       -6.0      -25.0     116.0       762
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I think because it's based on regex, it can lead to some unintended results, such as when there's other columns that contain 'year', 'month' and so on. But it's a nice one-liner

Comment: Yeah, I observed the dataset's columns beforehand on Kaggle, it depends on the case.

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd 
import janitor
from nycflights13 import flights

flights_sml = flights.select_columns(
                          slice('year', 'day'), 
                          '*delay', 
                          'distance', 
                          'air_time'
                       )

flights_sml.head()
   year  month  day  dep_delay  arr_delay  distance  air_time
0  2013      1    1        2.0       11.0      1400     227.0
1  2013      1    1        4.0       20.0      1416     227.0
2  2013      1    1        2.0       33.0      1089     160.0
3  2013      1    1       -1.0      -18.0      1576     183.0
4  2013      1    1       -6.0      -25.0       762     116.0
```

Comment: That's some good looking code. Didn't knoe about pyjanitor, definitely gonna take a look at it.